# Superset Dynamic Time Range Filter

Tags: dynamic, filtering, apache-superset

How can I set the all filters dynamically with a time range filter in superset?
For example, when I choose the time range last 28 days, I want to see the data of the relevant column for the last 28 days. As far as I know, the existing filters show all the data of the relevant column and are not affected by the time range. (and that increases the query cost a lot.)

The first thing that comes to my mind is to set the column related to the time range to have a parent child relationship, but I guess it doesn't support parent child relationship with time range.
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the first check-box option in the **Filter Configuration** ?

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfe2x.png)

Comment: Yes, i tried. If filter type is time range i can't select it in the values are dependent on other filters.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34006076)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am facing the same problem. The suggested filter configuration ("Values are dependent on other filters") does not support the date range filter, at least in Superset 2.1.0 that I am using.

Comment: Looks like this feature was recently added into the Superset 3.0, though - there you can select "Date Range" from the list of dependencies.